# how to add new table in nop commerce?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am newbie to nopcommerce and i've gone through all the steps which are :
Create The Entity Class (e.g Entity.cs)

Path : Nop/Core/Domain/Entity.cs
Create The Mapping Class (e.g EntityMap.cs)

Path : Nop/Data/Mapping/EntityMap.cs
Create a Model for MVC (e.g EntityModel.cs)

Path : Nop/Admin/Models/EntityModel.cs OR Nop/Web/Models/EntityModel.cs
Create a validator for model (e.g EntityValidator.cs)

Path : Nop/Admin/Validators/EntityValidator.cs OR Nop/Web/Validators/EntityValidator.cs
Create A Mapping Configuration On AutoMapperStartupTask.cs for Entity and Model

Path : Nop/Admin/Infrastructure OR Nop/Web/Infrastructure
Apply Mapping between Model and Entity on MappingExtensions.cs

Path : Nop/Admin OR Nop/Web
Create a service class and service interface (e.g EntityService.cs , IEntityService.cs)

Path : Nop/Services/EntityService.cs AND Nop/Services/IEntityService.cs
Register service for dependency injection

Path : Nop/Web/Framework/DependencyRegistrar.cs
Finally Create Controller and View for given model

but i'm not able to create a table and insert an entity by following these steps...
[here is the exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GcJ5H.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use code first entity framework you must first enable-migration in your console by write this command:

```
Enable-Migration
```

then after create entity and entity mapping in data layer, you can create first migration in console package manager like this:

```
Add-Migration start
```

after enter this command in console package manager first migration created and if you click on it you can see all inserted entities now you can write in console:

```
Update-Database
```

after all this steps you're entities will create successfully.
note: every time you create a new entity in core layer you must add migration and update database for you're database changes apply.

Comment: Thanks Maryam for the answer, but i've gone through all these migration steps and still not able to create a table in an existing nopCommerce database.. but when i create a table in sql server without a code first approach it works like a charm... any help..

Comment: maybe your connection strings in web.config not working well, if you're not check it till now, check this please and sure connection is stablished between your db and framework.

Comment: This is my connection string:
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="NopCommerce"
          connectionString="Data Source=ASAD\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=NopCommerce;Integrated Security=True"
          providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
if it is an issue of connection string then i guess it wouldn't work while creating a table manually and CRUD functionality works while creating a table in sql server

Comment: if you use sql server seperately and dont use it in your visual studio try this connection string  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="NopCommerce" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=NopCommerce;Integrated Security=SSPI; MultipleActiveResultSets=True;"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings> it worked for me because it connect sql server to your frame work out of visual studio and work on your localhost

Comment: __MigrationHistory table is there in the database but it is not creating a table named employee :/ Anyways maryam thanks for your help :)

Comment: i mean when you try enable-migration you can see a migration folder in your solution in project and when you add migration a migration create in that folder and see detail of inserted tables in it. i think if you'll fix your connection string you can see these things :)